# how to get <distance, length> pairs from ZLIB compressor

Tags: c, distance, zlib, string-length, lz77

I am compressing several long strings using ZLIB, which uses LZ77  representations of repeated substrings prior to encoding these representations using a Huffman tree.  I am interested in studying the sequence of  integer tuple representations themselves, and have been looking in the code to figure out where these are generated and how I could print them out one after another.  Unfortunately, I am not very strong in C, and it seems that the compressor handles distances as pointers, and not as ints.  Could somebody please tell me if there is a simple way to print out the sequence of  tuples as the algorithm runs, and point me to the appropriate location in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [infgen](https://github.com/madler/infgen) to disassemble a deflate stream. It will print the decoded symbols in a readable form, e.g. `match 41 105` indicating a string to copy of length 41, from a distance back of 105.